# How to serialize a property from another model in django rest?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models and two serializers. I'm trying to use a property from one this models.

I already tried using `foo = serializers.ReadOnlyField()` but doesn't work.

My example:

```py
class ExampleOne(models.Model):
    example_three = models.ForeignKey(
    "foo.ExampleThree",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="ones",
    )

    @property
    def foo(self):
    return bar
```

```py
class ExampleTwo(models.Model):
    example_four = models.ForeignKey(
    "foo.ExampleFour",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="twos",
    )
```

```py
class ExampleThree(models.Model):
    example_four = models.ForeignKey(
    "foo.ExampleFour",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="threes",
    )
```

```py
class ExampleFour(models.Model):
    ...
    fields=...
    ...
```

```py
class ExampleOneSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleOne
        fields = "__all__"
```

```py
class ExampleTwoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleTwo
        fields = "__all__"
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this porperty from another serializer?

Comment: Are your models actually in relation by a `ForeignKey` or a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: hey @frankie567 thanks. I update with more information.

Comment: Well, now there are four models? I'm not sure to understand which property you want to grab from which model.

Comment: hummm. @frankie567 the model `ExampleOne` has a property that I need. Sorry for 4 models, I put more details because of relationship.

Comment: From what I see you have One --> Three --> Four <-- Two. I don't see how you can retrieve a single value of One from Two.